# Fetching html on javascript document ready vs getting it on click of button through ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, document-ready

I have a webpage with a button. On click of that button, we want to display a HTML form. Following is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/5087/) for the same. We have 2 choices:

1. Get the html on document ready and show it only after button click. For example:

   ```
   $(document)on('ready', function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/getform/",
          success: function (data) {
             $("#view").html(data);
          }});
   });
   ```

Since this ajax call is on ready, it won't impact page load time. Downside is that user might not click the button and for such cases, we would unnecessarily bring this HTML if we go with this approach. What is the loss in getting extra HTML like this? Th

2. Get the HTML after the button click and then show it.

How to decide which appraoch is better?

Comment: How much data are we talking about here? A simple (or even one of the more complicated forms) shouldn't take up that much bandwidth to make a difference... Both approaches seem fine, if the majority of users were to click the button, load it in after the DOM is loaded, if only a few click the button, have them wait that split-second longer

Comment: Data is few KBs - not too big, nor too small. But click rate of button is quite low i.e. 1%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form isn't way too big (i.e. doesn't take that long to load) and not many people click the button in the first place, I would consider loading it when the button is clicked.

Show the users a loading icon, like this one:

[image]

and have them wait what little time it takes to load a "few KBs".

```js
$("#form-button").on('click', function () {
   $("#view").html(`<img src="spinner.gif" alt="Loading..." />`);
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/getform/",
       success: function (data) {
          $("#view").html(data);
       }});
});
```